# Android Application Bluetooth Connection Phone-PC

Tags: java, android, eclipse, bluetooth

I am trying to develop my Android application which would connect via bluetooth with PC computer and would be able to send data both ways. Like, sending string from Android application to PC and receiving the string on the screen and the other way aswell.

I am on my way to create the application on Android but I was wondering what would be the best way of resolving problem with PC: How would I send and receive the data? Firstly, I thought that I would need separate program but maybe there is some other way?

Could use ANY help on that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions for this problem.
Here is the one of possible solutions which could you use as a start point (https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/BluetoothChat).
 
Here is quick tutorial Simple Android and Java Bluetooth application (http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/)
Hope that helps.